# Missing LiveReload Server in Eclipse (JBoss Tools) and DevStudio

Tags: eclipse-plugin, jboss-tools

In Eclipse in the servers view the LiveReload Server is missing. If I want to add it, there is no option for it (Should be under Basic, but is not. -> see screenshot).

I have the current jboss tools installed and also tried the newest DevStudio. Even there the LiveReload Server was missing and could not be added.

How can I reinstall the LiveReload Server?

[Screenshot of Eclipse showing missing server :)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y9WBt.png)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The LiveReload plugin has been marked as deprecated and is no longer part of the basic installation of JBoss Tools (4.5.3) or Red Hat JBoss Developer Studio (11.3.0). You can still find it and install it from Red Hat Central.
1. Open Red Hat Central (e.g. Ctrl+3 for quick access, and type in "central")
2. Click the Software/Update tab at the bottom of Central
3. In the Find field, type in "livereload" to find the plugin
4. Check the plugin and click Install/Update at the bottom. Follow the dialog to install LiveReload
See here for more details: [JBIDE-25736](https://issues.jboss.org/browse/JBIDE-25736)